# Inverse limit and union of $\mathbb{Z} / p^{n}\mathbb{Z} $

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let the natural embeddings $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Z}/p^{2}\mathbb{Z} \subset  \dots \subset \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \subset  \dots $

*Questions*: Does the object $\bigcup_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$  make sense?
If so, what's the difference with the [inverse limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) $\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} =: \mathbb{Z}_p$ (the $p$-adic integers)?

Comment: There is not a "natural embedding" as you described. Or were you thinking of multiplication by $p$? Anyway, if you view cyclic groups of $p$-power order as roots of unity then that union (a direct limit) is isomorphic to the group of all $p$-power roots of unity, which is a countable torsion abelian group. On the other hand, the inverse limit you describe is the additive group of $p$-adic integers, which is an uncountable torsion-free abelian group. So these two groups are quite different. But in the sense of duality theory they are Pontryagin duals of each other, hence they are related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object $\bigcup_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is the *colimit* of the sequence

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \cdots$

where the maps are given by multiplication by $p$. This is known as the *Prüfer $p$-group* ([see nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Pr%C3%BCfer+group)). On the other hand, the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are the *limit* of the inverse system

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z} \leftarrow \cdots$

where the transition maps are given by taking residue classes.

Wikipedia claims that the ring of endomorphisms of the Prüfer $p$-group is given by $\mathbb{Z}_p$ ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group)).

Comment: Is the Prüfer p-group isomorphic to the group of p-power roots of unity? Is there a subgroup of it isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes, it is isomorphic to the group of $p$-power roots of unity, as pointed out by KCd in his comment (see also Wikipedia page). It does not have a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ as every element has finite order.